# KDE changes mouse cursor when it is on window frame

Tags: arch-linux, kde, graphics

As you can see on this gif, my mouse cursor changes, when I move it to window frame. It is little annoying. I am using KDE Plazma.

[image: screengif]

My specs:

`````
                   -`                    samtulach@ProPC
                  .o+`                   ---------------
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64
                `+oooo:                  Kernel: 4.14.22-1-lts
               `+oooooo:                 Uptime: 30 mins
               -+oooooo+:                Packages: 846
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Shell: bash 4.4.19
            `/++++/+++++++:              Resolution: 1920x1080
           `/++++++++++++++:             DE: KDE
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           WM: KWin
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK2/3]
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         Icons: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK2/3]
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Terminal: konsole
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Terminal Font: Hack 11
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       CPU: Intel i5-7400 (4) @ 3.500GHz
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    Memory: 1374MiB / 7923MiB
 `++:.                           `-/+/ 
 .`                                 `/
`````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Found solution:

Edit */usr/share/icons/default/index.theme*

Replace: `Inherits=Adwaita`

To: `Inherits=breeze_cursors`